# Flexslider hide clone

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have a problem with Flexslider 2.2.2. I use flexslider to show some product thumbnail images inside a carousel. The problem is that when the product only have one image there are two thumbnails shown. One original and a clone of the original image!

Is there a way to hide the clone? 
I found [this](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/975) issue on Github but I'm not sure if that's the exact same problem.

Below an image. So the problem is that "thumb1 clone" is also showed instead of hidden.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Meules, I have exactly the same issue... Did you succeed by reparing it ?

Comment: @Gealle: unfortunately not :( I tried owl carousel instead which does the job better since it's a better plugin if your images need to be responsive aswell!

Comment: finally i abandoned it too and used BxSlider instead. Apparently it is a bug, and moothemes provided some fixes but they did not work for me...

Answer (score 0):

In the file **flexslider.js** look for the line with that code "**slider.cloneOffset**" and set the value to **2**